# Linux command line log viewer which allows auto tail AND searching?

Tags: linux, logging, less, tail

I use `tail -f` in my Linux shell, to view log files, as I like how it auto-updates with the incoming text: I like to see the new stuff come scrolling in.

However, I also like the search functionality of `less`, which isn't available in `tail` (or is it?).  Is there a "best of both worlds" solution?

If there was a mode I could switch on in `less` which would make it auto-update with incoming text, then that might be ideal.

Comment: Does it have to be a simple command or would you accept using a Node.JS command line application?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can run `less +F filename` in order to view file in `tail -f` fashion.

You can press Shift+F while viewing file in **less** to switch to forwarding mode, and Ctrl+C to leave this mode.

Comment: Or Shift-End for continuous update.

Answer (score 5):

From `less -help`:

> F                    Forward forever; like "tail -f".

so presumably  `less +F /var/log/messages`

Comment: You can also press Shift+F while viewing file in **less** to switch to forwarding mode, and Ctrl+C to leave this mode.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 - starting it with "less -F <file>" doesn't work for me.  @Nikolai - `shift&f` is perfect, thanks!  If you want to make that an answer i'll mark it as correct.  (btw, in case anyone else is reading, to get out of forwarding mode, it's `ctrl&c`, or whatever your regular cancel/interrupt keycode is.

Answer (score 3):

Nicolai's answer is probably closest to what you asked for, but have you thought about using tmux?

In my tmux sessions, I like to `tail -f` logs, then simply enter tmux's copy mode to search up and down exactly like searching in less, then exit copy mode to find my `tail -f` still going.

Create a tmux session:

```
tmux
```

Tail the log file and the last 1000 lines to start:

```
tail -f -n1000 /var/log/syslog
```

Enter copy mode using the leader key and a left bracket:

```
[ctrl+leader] + [
```

the default tmux leader key is the letter b, so for example:

```
[ctrl+b] [
```

Now you can scroll and search up and down just like in less.

Exit copy mode to return to your `tail -f` with:

```
[crtl+c]
```

Bonus material:
Open a second terminal prompt:

```
[ctrl+leader] + c
```

Switch between the two terminal prompts:

```
[ctrl+leader] + l
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
tailf logname.log | grep "query-here"
```